# Display elements in a list based off object type in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, collections, instanceof

Suppose I have an interface called Vechicle, and two classess (Car and Bike) that implement it.

I want to have a list containing cars and bikes. How would I go about making a method that displays the number of both bikes and cars?  I was thinking about making a variable that counts each instance of a Bike/Car in a list, and then it increments it based on that, howevere, if I later on want to add another vehicle (suppose a Truck) then I would have to create another variable that counts the number of trucks and so on and so forth.

```
public interface Vehicle {
   void vehicleName();
}

public class Car implements Vehicle{

    @Override
    public String vehicleName() {
        System.out.println("I'm a car");
    }
    
}

public class Bike implements Vehicle{

    @Override
    public String vehicleName() {
        System.out.println("I'm a bike");
    }
    
}


public class Transportation {

List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I later on want to add another vehicle

Is a the right problem, your got it. The idea is to make your code independant of the actual classes and generic enough to new situations.

---

For that you could use a `Map` that will store class name as key, and count as value

```
Map<String, Integer> getCounts() {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
        counts.merge(v.getClass().getSimpleName(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

Using `Stream` that can be done with `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Map<String, Long> getCounts() {
    return vehicleList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.getClass().getSimpleName(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have not yet got to maps, but I'll look into them.
Using this approach, is there a way I could, for instance, let's say a Client wanted to buy 3 bikes, and we have only 2, compare the return of the getCounts() with the input of a Client?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Map where the key is the `Class` of the vehicle instance and value is the count (number of times that particular type is present in the list).

```
 Map<Class<? extends Vehicle>, Long> result = vehicleList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Vehicle::getClass, Collectors.counting()));
```

Say, you have two Cars and one Bike, then printing the `result` map will print the canonical class name like,

```
{class <your_java_package_path>.Bike=1, class <your_java_package_path>.Car=2}
```

To get the simple class name, call the `getSimpleName` as:

```
result.forEach((clazz, count) -> System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName() + " " + count));
```

This will print,

```
Bike 1
Car 2
```

Thus, when you add a new `Vehicle` type in the future, no changes need to be done to the above code.

**UPDATE:** You can simplify this by caling `Class#getSimpleName` when building the map itself - See [azro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67956291/4405757)